# Error: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

```
int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

        }

        label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Above is the code to calculate.
When I run the application it displays no errors. After I load the datagridview from MySql and press the button that leads to the above function it displays error.

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
```

[Here is an example of the datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifZfN.png)

If I change Cells[2] to Cells[0] it works fine

I am still a C# beginner, but Im guessing it is unable to convert the data in 'earned' column to integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your screenshot, `Cells[2]` isn't an `int` but a `Decimal` and sum should be declared such type.

```
Decimal sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;++i)
{
    sum += Decimal.Parse((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ?? "").ToString());
}
```

If, for some reasons the value is empty or wrong, there's a way to check if the conversion was succesful using [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
Decimal sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;++i)
{
    Decimal temp;
    if (Decimal.TryParse((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ?? "").ToString(), out temp))
        sum += temp;
}

label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Note : `(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ?? "")` will perform a check against `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value`. If it's null, the value `""` will be used instead of `null`. `null.ToString()` will throw an exception.

Comment: Probably `decimal` is a better choice (`earned` seems to be *money*)

Comment: Sorry, but again (see Amin Mozhgani's answer): `Decimal.TryParse` / `Decimal.Parse` wants `string`, not `object` (`Value` is of type `object`)

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.

Comment: But if i change Value to Value? 
it displays a number

Comment: `(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ?? "").ToString()` throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the field has a numeric value and then convert it to int.

```
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;++i)
{
    float temp = 0;
    float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value?.ToString(), out temp);
    sum += temp;

}

label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: `Value` is of type `object`, that why `int.TryParse` *doesn't compile* (`int.TryParse` wants `string`)

Comment: it says 'no overload for method TryParse takes 1 argument

Comment: @OmarMohamed changed

Comment: `Value?.ToString()` - note `?` to be on the *safe side* if `Value` is `null`

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.

Comment: @OmarMohamed Dmitry was right, you should check if value is null, I changed it, test it please.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ` is returning null value

Comment: @AminMozhgani It didnt display an error now, but it displayed the sum as 0

Comment: This can also be done in this way `int.TryParse((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value??0).ToString(), out temp);`

Comment: @OmarMohamed what's the data type of your field in your DB?

Comment: @AminMozhgani in db, type is Varchar100

Comment: Are they pure int values or decimal ones?

Comment: @AminMozhgani decimal ones up to 0.xxx

Comment: So you should change int to float

Comment: The actual problem is not with data type. You are starting loop from index "0". And for DataGridView object there is always header row on "0" index. That's why on very first iteration you get Cell value null. The proper solution is to start loop from 1st index or simply put a null check as I mentioned in my earlier comments.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal check the last comment of Omar, the data is in decimal type and if you try to cast it as int, it always returns 0 (because tryParse returns false)

Comment: @AminMozhgani absolutely right. Data type is in varchar and it can not be converted in int. But can be casted into float or double.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal If the stored varchar is in int format, it can be cast to int, but in this case, we have decimal-like varchars. Good luck my bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Decimal sumcol = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;++i)
{
Decimal val;
string colval = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
if(colval  != null){
 if (Decimal.TryParse(colval, out val))
    sum += val;
}

label1.Text = sum.ToString();}
```

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();` will throw an exception if `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value` is null

Comment: you can use.Text instead of Value also like  'gvw_Search.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();'